# Siri Remote's Menu Button not exiting application when UIButton is focused

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, siri-remote

I'm overriding `pressesBegan` to receive Select presses. The Siri Remote's Menu Button does not exit my application when the focus is on a `UIButton`. If no UI element is focused the Menu Button works as expected.

How do I receive Menu Button presses when the focus is on a `UIButton`?

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for item in presses {
        if item.type == .Select {
            print("Click")
        }
        if item.type == .Menu {
            print("Menu Button")
            super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIButton` only responds to the `.Select` button on the remote. You can catch the menu button using a tap gesture recognizer. For example:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ClassName.menuPressed()))
tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)];
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Then implement:

```
func menuPressed() {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This works great. Forgot about using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Is there a way to return to the home screen gracefully rather than `exit(0)`?

Comment: Nevermind, got it: `UIControl().sendAction(#selector(NSURLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.sharedApplication(), forEvent: nil)` Thank you!